# Muonic Hydrogen Dissociation

Tags: fusion, quantum-chemistry

Is the dissociation energy of a muonic molecular hydrogen ion the same as an ordinary molecular hydrogen ion? Would the cross-section for dissociation be the same as an ordinary molecular hydrogen ion? I am trying to determine the fusion rate for muon-catalyzed fusion in warm dense plasma, and I need to know the dissociation rate of a muonic hydrogen molecule due to electron collisions.

Comment: I’d expect the dissociation energy of the molecule to be much higher. For an atom, the binding energy of the muonic ground state is 207 times higher than the electronic ground state, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, ionization energy is proportional to the mass of the electron (or muon).